# I cannot install bindex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've cloned my own app from Heroku (where it works prefectly fine) and want to run a server on my machine to edit the app.

I'm trying to bundle my gems, but I receive the message:

```
 An error occurred while installing bindex (0.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install bindex -v '0.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This is followed by:

```
In Gemfile:
  web-console was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
    bindex
```

So I ran `gem install bindex -v '0.5.0'`, but still get `Error installing bindex`.

How can I get around this?

Thanks.